# Storing wins and losses locally in Unity

Tags: unity, c#

I am writing here as I have made a game in Unity where I want to store how many wins/losses a player has. The way I am thinking to do it is by putting 2 counters; One for every time a player wins, and one for every time a player loses. What I do when a player wins or loses is that he can shoot something and restart the game; I load scene 0 here. I know that the counters will reset once the player closes the application, but that doesn't matter.

Anyway, is there a better way to do it?

The other thing I am thinking about is storing how many times a player has played the game in total, and this has to be stores locally too and must not get reset when the player closes the application. How is this done?

Comment: Sounds like you should read up about Unity's [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) API.

Comment: I have read a little about it, but I can't see how I should use it. I have to use Save() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want settings to persist after the application is closed, you should be using `PlayerPrefs`.  To set a value, you use the functions provided by the `PlaylerPrefs` class (`SetInt`, `SetFloat`, `SetString`)

```
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score", 10);
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

When you want to retrieve this setting you would use the appropriate `Get` function:

```
int score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score");
```

You can also clear the player preferences data:

```
PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll();
PlayerPrefs.Save();
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot :) Is 10 the score or must it be written? Cause in the manual they are not telling what it is used for

Comment: You can pass in any variable of type integer in the SetInt() function.  The 10 is just a random value I used to demonstrate how the function would be used.

Comment: Can't this be tested with the editor? Because When I close the game and start it again it haven't stored the previous values.

Comment: Yes it should work just fine.  Make sure you are not overwriting the previously saved value when you are loading up your scene.

Comment: I have put the save and setint in the methods where I count the wins and where I count the losses. In start I only have the declarations

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your code?  I"ll take a look at it.

Comment: It is a nooby mistake :) I initialized a new variable instead of using the one I already had :))